# Use Ancestor ItemsSource in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Class:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public List<Example> ListExample { get; }
}
class Example
{
    public List<string> Names { get; }
    public Visibility IsVisible { get; }
    public List<Example> Children { get; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListExample}"
              Name="Base">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      ...
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
                Name="List1">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              ...
              <StackPanel>
                  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }"/>
                  <Expander Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}">
                      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                                Name="List2">
                          ...
                      </ListView>
                  </Expander>
              </StackPanel>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I already tried various RelativeSource approaches but couldn't get it to work.

Since I bound Names in List1 as the ItemsSource, I can't access Children in List2 or IsVisible in the Expander.
I want to know wether it is possible to get back to the Example Element from ListExample in the ItemsControl.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, an itemsource takes a list of items and builds a list of controls from it the item source has no relevance inside the created item, if you want the item that was used to create the contol then that is in the dataDontext  if the datatemplate

Comment: You need to provide the classes you are binding to, because it's not clear how they look like.

Comment: give me one minute, I will provide a class model

Comment: So you want to display list of examples, in each example list of names and under each name list of child examples?

Comment: yes, displaying the names again, I didn't list that because the moment I have the children as an ItemsSource I can access them without a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to the `DataContext` of the parent `ListView` using a `{RelativeSource}` like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListExample}" Name="Base">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" Name="List1">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                            <Expander Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}">
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Children, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" Name="List2">
                                </ListView>
                            </Expander>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Both answers work, I just like this one a little better.

Answer (score 1):

given following models:

```
class ViewModel
{
   public List<Example> Examples { get; }
}

class Example
{
   public List<string> A {get;}
   public Visibility B {get;}
   public List<string> C {get;}
}
```

it would look like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Examples}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      ...
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding A}"
                Name="List1">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              ...
              <StackPanel>
                  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }"/>
                  <Expander Visibility="{Binding DataContext.B, ElementName=List1}">
                      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.C, ElementName=List1}"
                                Name="List2">
                          ...
                      </ListView>
                  </Expander>
              </StackPanel>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: so the ItemsSource set in List1 applies to the inner elements but not List1 itself?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In the topmost ItemsControl, the items binds to Example class. Items in the List1 ListView binds to string, because you set ItemsSource to list of strings.